# Garbage collect my gnome-shell memory!

Tags: gnome3, gnome-shell, memory-leaks

I use Gnome/Wayland (Fedora distro) almost exclusively and enjoy its features.  However, `gnome-shell` consistently consumes more and more memory as a result of it not releasing unused memory.  Eventually, I even need to close everything and log out/in so that I can recover some RAM to do my work.

Georges Stavracas, in [*The Infamous GNOME Shell Memory Leak*](https://feaneron.com/2018/04/20/the-infamous-gnome-shell-memory-leak/), describes the problem and a work-around that will appear in future Gnome releases.  Early reports indicate that the work-around is successful.

Until all the distros catch up to the latest Gnome release, is there a way to recover the gnome-shell lost memory manually?  `lookingglass` `imports.system.gc()` doesn't seem to do it on it's own.  I'd much prefer to occasionally run a program than to save/close everything, log out/in, reopen/reload everything, and continue working.

Is there something that does this?  Is it possible?

Answer (score -1):

I use `gnome-shell -r` to release memory. 
You can use it in cron to do it frequently.

Comment: According for `genome-shell` man, the flag `-r`, or `--replace` means
replace the running window manager, not releasing the memory!!

Comment: @Goro If the program leaks memory, restarting it still helps.

Comment: @RalfFriedl. Completely agree! ;-)